# What does the 'gimp_histogram' procedure require to work?

Tags: gimp, script-fu, gimpfu, python-fu

I do not understand why my call to `pdb.gimp_histogram` throws a `RuntimeError: execution error`.

```
from gimpfu import *

def plugin_main ( timg, tdrawable ):

    pdb.gimp_histogram( tdrawable, 0, 0, 255 )
```

According to the [docs](http://oldhome.schmorp.de/marc/pdb/gimp_histogram.html), the function takes four arguments:

- drawable ( type drawable)
- channel to modify ( type int )
- start range ( type int )
- end range ( type int)

I provide all four in the barebones code above, so why is the error thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks correct (I have similar code that works).

However I get the same error if the image is color-indexed, while the doc says "*The drawable may not be indexed.*", so that could be your problem?

PS: You should use the named constants (`HISTOGRAM_{VALUE|RED|BLUE|GREEN|ALPHA}`)

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! That's exactly the problem. I somehow missed that part when reading. I was using the histogram window for testing and it works with indexed images so I just assumed the procedure would be the same. Is the solution then to create a temporary version of the image that is another format and use that to get the histogram data? (I am trying to count pixels by color).

Comment: No better way off the top of my head, but it's getting late here.